# What if any are people's experience of Reliability, security and/or overall interaction with Syncfrog?

Tags: data-loader, data-export, data-synchronization, sync

I'm looking into Syncfrog as a possible app for taking data and migrating it from Google Docs to Salesforce as a measure of updating existing contacts rather than creation. I was going to test it out with the Basic package but before investing too much time into that I was hoping someone can give pros/cons and overall experience they've had with it.